# How do I migrate data from one table into another, the rows in table1 being columns in table2?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datatable, data-migration

I have found several similar questions but none seems to answer my question exactly, and I'm not very good at SQL, so here is my problem:

I have `table 1` with multiple rows;

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | v1 |
| name2 | v2 |
| name3 | v3 |
| name4 | v4 |
| name5 | v5 |

and I want to migrate those rows (specific ones - like name1, name2, name3) into one single row in a different table, where the columns would match the names.

And here is `table 2`:

| id | n1 | n2 | n3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | v2 | v2 | v3 |

I would probably know how to write SQL that would do that, but only row by row.
What would be a good clean way of migrating that data? Ideally I would also delete the rows in table 1 after that was done.

Comment: Do you really want 1800 columns if table1 has 1800 rows?

Comment: it is only a few selected rows which i know the names (they will be specific name1, name2, name3). I will edit my question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Look up "SQL case expression pivot". You'll find a million examples.

Comment: @shawnt00 this pivot thing seems to use the name of the value in the row as the column. but i am creating new column names that not necessarily match the value in the row. does it mean that i have to do one by one insert into blah .. select value where name = 'name1' ?

Comment: @solarapricot You can change the aliases in the query output. I'm not entirely sure what to picture regarding the final destination of your result.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you want to aggregate your results and insert into an empty table. The names from the query won't have to match. What's relevant is the correspondence between names in the `insert` columns listed between parentheses in the same order as the `select` output.

```
insert into t2 (id, matchForN1, matchForN2, matchForN3, ...)
select
    id,
    min(name) filter (where name = 'name1') as n1,
    min(name) filter (where name = 'name2') as n2,
    min(name) filter (where name = 'name3') as n3 ...
from t1
where name in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3' ...)
group by id
```